# StackOverflowError when trying to deploy an application to Weblogic?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear, stack-overflow

I am working on a J2EE application, to deploy I am using a *build.xml* (which is used by all team members) to create ear & publish, after the *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* message appears in Eclipse, I start **Weblogic 10.3.2** but weblogic doesn't start properly and shows the following error message in the console:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [zip:C:/APP1/P2/2.0.0/Code/tools/bea_10.3.2/user_projects
/domains/knb_local/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/APP1Web/epxawd/war/WEB-INF/li
b/slf4j-jcl-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [zip:C:/APP1/P2/2.0.0/Code/tools/bea_10.3.2/user_projects
/domains/knb_local/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/APP1Web/epxawd/war/WEB-INF/li
b/slf4j-jcl-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [zip:C:/APP1/P2/2.0.0/Code/tools/bea_10.3.2/user_projects
/domains/knb_local/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/APP1Web/epxawd/war/WEB-INF/li
b/app1-shared-4.0.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
<Jun 29, 2010 4:14:44 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.appgw.base.web.startup.APP1WebStartup failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:438)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:222)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:218)

        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:370)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

........................
........................
```

**(If I launch the application I get Error 404--Not Found)**

The strange thing is that the problem is only with my machine whereas other team members are able to successfully deploy and start weblogic. I am using the same code from CVS.

It may be an issue with the environment (like default JRE etc..)

**Any ideas ? What could be the problem**

```
Windows XP / Weblogic 10.3.2
java -version
java version "1.6.0_19"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.2-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar [issue here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2395948) (bottom of the chain) suggests keeping only slf4j-api-1.5.x.jar and slf4f-simple-1.5.x.jar in your WEB-INF/lib and removing any other slf4j jars from there?